# How do I align objects relative to center in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

Let's say I have two vertical lines A and B. How do I align them to be the same distance from the (vertical) mid-center line C? Preferably so that I can enter a percentage somewhere, but it is not strictly necessary.

(I can handle the special case of aligning them to 1/3 and 2/3, respectively, by using the "Distribute" tool, but how would I arrange having them, say, at being at 40% and 60%, respectively?)

Comment: Please read the Tag Wiki for inkscape (just over your mouse over the tag, or click on it) to learn where you should ask questions about it. This question will find better answers on the Graphics SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to position precisely an object to some arbitrary position:

1. Enter directly the coordinates in the "Tool Control Bar" of the "Select" tool (the standard black mouse pointer, <kbd>F1</kbd>). You may have to calculate the position you want, and it'll be the top-left coordinate.
2. Use the "Objects > Transform" dialog in this way:

   1. Align all objects vertically,
   2. Use the "Move" tab of the "Transform" tool